# Exception in one activity doesn't stop other activities

Tags: android, exception, android-activity

My OnCreate method (in MainActivity):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            // This will throw exception
            Integer.parseInt("Güzelim");
        }
    });
}
```

When a button is clicked, the app crashes; showing the dialog "Unfortunately app has stopped".  When I click <kbd>OK</kbd> button, the DetailsActivity screen is displayed.  Why does this happen?  I would like the entire app to crash.

Comment: call  Integer.parseInt("Güzelim"); before starting your activity

Comment: handle this exception by using try catch in your on create method

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           // This will throw exception
        Integer.parseInt("Güzelim");

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

This should crash your whole app.

Comment: Thanks I understand that but I'd like someone to explain why my code works how it works. I mean why happens behind the scene? Is each activity running in the separate process or what? I just don't understand why entire app doesn't crash but just part of it (MainActivity).

Answer (score 0):

App is crashing because you are trying to convert String into Integer which is throwing NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4390786/1529129) to a similar question might help

> For example, a user might be browsing the web, click a youtube link
>   launching the youtube app, then click a share button to launch their
>   favorite social networking app and post the video link. This is all
>   part of the same task; if the user presses back several times they'll
>   come back to the page in the browser that they started from.
>
> Once you start up the social networking app, the system might decide
>   that it's running low on memory and it's going to kill off the
>   browser's process to free up more. (After all, it's not in front and
>   the user won't notice.) When the user presses the back button to
>   return to the browser Activity it gets restarted and reconstructs the
>   last state where the user left it. At worst the user experiences a
>   short delay while things reinitialize.
>
> But this same sequence of events restoring a previous Activity state
>   can happen even within the same app in the same process. In your
>   scenario, Activity B closed as the result of the crash. So the system
>   does exactly what it always does - it returns to the previous
>   Activity: Activity A. But Activity A's process isn't still around (it
>   crashed!) so the system restarts it and it can reconstruct its
>   previous state.

Crux of discussion: As a philosophy Android tries to give a feel that all the apps are running all the time, as part of this philosophy it tries to restore from neatest point possible.